# Is there a way to code this using dplyr in a more convenient way?

Tags: r, analysis

For future reference, if needed to change some values to binary or characters, any other quick way to do this would be appreciated.

```
elite <- rep("No", nrow(college))
elite[college$Top10perc > 50] = "Yes"
elite <- as.factor(elite)
```

*top10perc = quantitative

Answer (score 0):

```
elite <- factor(ifelse(college$Top10perc > 50, 'Yes', 'No'))
```

Comment: Appreciated mate !